# How do I count the number of times a variable's value has been used?

Tags: c, counter

very new to C. I have a problem where I need to keep a running total of the use of several variables whose values are denominations of currency, in order to get a final total of their count, up to the input value being zero. For example, given $2.45, how many times is 10¢ used and how many times is 5¢ used until the value is 0?

I thought to use a for-loop with a counter, but I only ever increment a variable's value and not actually count the number of times it has been used, while the counter doesn't get used at all.

```
int count = 0;

if (cents > quarter)
 {
    for (int i = quarter; i < 1; i++)
    {
        new_val = cents/quarter;
        count++;
        printf("count %i\n", count);
    }
  }
```

All variables have been declared and/or initialised.

I know the algorithmm is completely incorrect; I do not know how to correct it. Some insight would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use division to get the number of each coin.

Then add them together to get the total coin count.

```
const quarter = 25, dime = 10, nickel = 5;
int quarters, dimes, nickels, pennies, count;

int cents = 245;

quarters = cents / quarter; // how many quarters are needed
cents = cents % quarter; // the remainder after using all the quarters

dimes = cents / dime; // how many dimes are needed
cents = cents % dime; // the remainder after using all the dimes

nickels = cents / nickel; // how many nickels are needed
cents = cents % nickel; // the remainder after using all the nickels

pennies = cents; // pennies are everything left over

count = quarters + dimes + nickels + pennies;
```

Comment: Thank you both, for the suggestions. I had thought ot both ways of implementing the algorithm, but not far enough for each. Indeed, a good start. One perplexing matter is how to count the actual number of coins used. So, $2.45 =245¢ = 9 x25¢ + 2 x 10¢ = 11 coins; the counter is the real issue.

Comment: `count = quarters + dimes + nickels + pennies`

Answer (score 1):

Here's the general outline:

- You need a way to keep track of the number of quarters, dimes, nickels, and pennies.  The easiest way is to create separate variables for each, initialized to `0`:

  ```
  int quarters=0, dimes=0, nickels=0, pennies=0;
  ```

  You could also use an array:

  ```
  int coins[4] = {0};
  ```

  and just keep track of what denomination is stored at which index (i.e., quarters are stored at index 0, dimes at index 1, etc.).

  For each denomination, subtract that amount from the input until the input value is less than that denomination:`/**
   * Assume input value is in pennies, so $2.45 would be represented as 245
   */
  while ( input > 0 && input >= 25 )
  {
    input -= 25;
    quarters++; // or coins[0]++ if you're using the array method.
  }`
  You'd repeat that for each denomination.  You can be extra tricky and use another array as a lookup table for the denomination values so you could do it all in a single loop, but this should get you going.

**Edit**

Or you could go with Barmar's method and avoid loops altogether.

Comment: Please see Barmar. Apparently, I cannot add two names to a comment. Is it possible to share the vote? You both deserve it.

Answer (score 0):

```c
struct intVarCounter
{
    int var;
    int gets;
    int sets;
    int adds;
    // you can have more or remove some,
    // but this is it for this example.
};
void init(intVarCounter *ivc, int value)
{
    *ivc.var=value;
    *ivc.gets=0;
    *ivc.sets=0;
    *ivc.adds=0;
    // remember to remove or add to these
    // if you change the struct's properties
}
int get(intVarCounter *ivc)
{
    *ivc.gets++;
    return *ivc.var;
}
int set(intVarCounter *ivc, int value)
{
    *ivc.set++;
    *ivc.var=value;
    return *ivc.var;
}
int add(intVarCounter *ivc, int addend)
{
    *ivc.adds++;
    *ivc.var+=addend;
    return *ivc.var;
}
int main()
{
    intVarCounter *ivc;
    init(ivc,0);
    set(ivc,10);
    printf("%d",*ivc.sets);
    add(ivc,10);
    printf("%d %d", get(ivc), *ivc.gets);
    return add(ivc,-20);
}
```

This creates a simple structure that basically wraps the variable so that it tracks whenever you get, set, or add to it.  If you want to change it, it is very simple; just add/remove that property and add/remove it's associated function.

There are problems with this though.  You can directly change the `ivc.var`, effectively bypassing the counter.  You also have to use the `init` function all of the time, otherwise you get strange looking variable values.  You can also change the number of `get`s, `set`s, etc. .  This can be fixed with `C++`:

```cpp
class intVarCounter
{
    int var; // automatically private to prevent direct change
    int gets;
    int sets;
    int adds;
    // ... you can add/remove these
    public:
        intVarCounter(int value=0)
        {
            int var=value;
            int gets=0;
            int sets=0;
            int adds=0;
        }
        int get()
        {
            gets++;  // you can remove this line to prevent gets tracking
            return var;
        }
        int set(int value=0)
        {
            sets++;  // same here but with sets tracking
            var=value;
            return var;
        }
        int add(int addend=1)
        {
            adds++;
            var+=addend;
            return var;
        }
        int getProp(char *propName) // get the number of gets, sets, etc.
        {
            if(!strcmp(propName,"gets"))
                return gets;
            else if(!strcmp(propName,"sets"))
                return sets;
            else if(!strcmp(propName,"adds"))
                return adds;
            // add/remove from here if you want
            else
                return 0;
        }
        // you can add more public functions here
};
```

This is just the `class` of `intVarCounter`.  As you can see, `C++` has solved all of our problems.  The tag of this question is [c](/questions/tagged/c), but this is for those who want to use `C++` instead.  The `C` way isn't that bad anyways if no external programs will mess up your counter.

All of the other answers (at the time of posting) have given ways based on the amount of money, but this works for most of your cases, even without money included in the problem.  Try it and tell me in the comments if it worked!

Comment: Thank you for your solutions, both in C and C++. I will certainly try them, but unfortunately, I cannot include either in my program because they are at a level indicative of someone more knowledgeable than my program exercise requires and certainly beyond my current level of attainment. Nonetheless, much appreciated.

Comment: @Den Thank you for your response.  I understand your situation and I hope the accepted answer is a good one for you to use. 